# How to stop my Python game code to close right after line 3-4?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started to learn how to program three days ago. I decided to learn Python, version 3.7.2. Today I wrote this code trying to create a game in which you enter a username and play rock, paper, scissors against a bot. However right after I enter my username (line 2-4), the Python shell closes. I am running the program by clicking on the file in My Explorer, Windows 10. I suppose this is a simple beginner mistake, can someone please help out?

I tried adding input() at line 4. When I do this, the Python shell does not close after entering the username. It does nothing, just newline. And when I type something in that newline and press Enter, the shell closes.

Here's my code:

```
import random
print('Hello, welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors. Enter your name to get started.')
usn = input()

def game(choice):
  options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
  bot = random.choice(options)
  if choice == 'rock' and bot == 'scissors':
    print(usn + ' played rock, I played scissors. You won. Nice!')
  elif choice == 'rock' and bot == 'paper':
    print(usn + ' played rock, I played paper. You lost. Haha, loser!')
  elif choice == 'paper' and bot == 'scissors':
    print(usn + ' played paper, I played scissors. You lost. Haha, loser!')
  elif choice == 'paper' and bot == 'rock':
    print(usn + ' played paper, I played rock. You won. Nice!')
  elif choice == 'scissors' and bot == 'paper':
    print(usn + ' played scissors, I played paper. You won. Nice!')
  elif choice == 'scissors' and bot == 'rocks':
    print(usn + ' played scissors, I played rocks. You lost. Haha, loser!')
  elif choice == bot:
    print("It's a draw, dang it!")

def again(x):
    while True:
        if x == 'Yes':
            game(input('Rock, Paper or Scissors?'))
            again(input('Want to play again? Yes or No'))
        else:
            print('Goodbye. Press Enter to exit.')
            input()
```

Expected: I expected that after I enter a username, I can enter either rock, paper or scissors and then the game would play.
Actual result: Python shell closes after entering the username.

Comment: It closes because your code doesn't call any of the functions after receiving the username.

Comment: You're not calling any of the functions you define after the input

Comment: Thank y'all for being so helpful and beginner-friendly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `game` too -- though `game` needs to be declared at that point.

I refactored things a little here and made them a little more convenient for the user.

- The argument names used in `game` are `username` and `user_choice`, so as not to shadow the global names (or use them by accident).
- The `again()` recursive function is replaced by a `while` loop that's `break`ed out of when the user says they don't want to play again.
- The RPS and again question inputs are lower-cased and stripped, so the user entering, say, "      NO ", "nO", "pAPeR", etc. works.

The next thing I'd recommend thinking about is how to simplify the repetition in the `game` function. :)

```py
import random


def game(username, user_choice):
    options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    bot = random.choice(options)
    if user_choice == 'rock' and bot == 'scissors':
        print(username + ' played rock, I played scissors. You won. Nice!')
    elif user_choice == 'rock' and bot == 'paper':
        print(username + ' played rock, I played paper. You lost. Haha, loser!')
    elif user_choice == 'paper' and bot == 'scissors':
        print(username + ' played paper, I played scissors. You lost. Haha, loser!')
    elif user_choice == 'paper' and bot == 'rock':
        print(username + ' played paper, I played rock. You won. Nice!')
    elif user_choice == 'scissors' and bot == 'paper':
        print(username + ' played scissors, I played paper. You won. Nice!')
    elif user_choice == 'scissors' and bot == 'rocks':
        print(username + ' played scissors, I played rocks. You lost. Haha, loser!')
    elif user_choice == bot:
        print("It's a draw, dang it!")


print('Hello, welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors. Enter your name to get started.')
name = input()

while True:  # do forever, unless `break`ed out of (or an exception occurs)
    choice = input('Rock, Paper or Scissors?').lower().strip()
    game(name, choice)
    if input('Want to play again? Yes or No').lower().strip() == 'no':
        print('Goodbye. Press Enter to exit.')
        input()
        break  # break out of the "while true" loop
```

Comment: @DungChiPham Everyone's a noob at least once. :)

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that you are not calling any function after receiving the user name I would try something like this (notice that i added some comments to the code):

```
import random
print('Hello, welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors. Enter your name to get started.')
usn = input()

def game(choice):
  options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
  bot = random.choice(options)
  if choice == 'rock' and bot == 'scissors':
    print(usn + ' played rock, I played scissors. You won. Nice!')
  elif choice == 'rock' and bot == 'paper':
    print(usn + ' played rock, I played paper. You lost. Haha, loser!')
  elif choice == 'paper' and bot == 'scissors':
    print(usn + ' played paper, I played scissors. You lost. Haha, loser!')
  elif choice == 'paper' and bot == 'rock':
    print(usn + ' played paper, I played rock. You won. Nice!')
  elif choice == 'scissors' and bot == 'paper':
    print(usn + ' played scissors, I played paper. You won. Nice!')
  elif choice == 'scissors' and bot == 'rocks':
    print(usn + ' played scissors, I played rocks. You lost. Haha, loser!')
  elif choice == bot:
    print("It's a draw, dang it!")

# Taking this out of the function, it is going to be called right on the execution
x = 'Yes' 
while True: #here you are doing an loop, that will only end when break is called
    if x == 'Yes':
        game(input('Rock, Paper or Scissors?'))
        x = input('Want to play again? Yes or No')
    else:
        print('Goodbye. Press Enter to exit.')
        input()
        break
```

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting me! I learned from experience like this :)

Answer (score -1):

`def game(choice):` creates a function named `game`. you need to tell python to execute this function with one parameter: `choice`
like so: `game(usn)`

Comment: The `choice` argument should be the user's choice of rock, paper or scissors, not the username.